# scaleable diamond pattern with javascript

Tags: javascript

Very new to javascript, a few weeks. My goal is create a scaleable diamond.

This is the code I have so far.

```
var board = '';
var dimondX = 4;
var dimondY = 4;
  for (y = 0; y <= dimondY; y++) {
    for(x = 0; x <= dimondX; x++) {
        if ((y == 0 || y == dimondY ) && (x == dimondX / 2 )){ 
        board += "#" }  
        else if (( y == 1 || y == 3) && (x == 3 || x ==1 )) {
        board += "#" }
        else if (( y == dimondY / 2) && (x % 2 == 0)) {
        board += "#" }
        else { 
        board += " " }
    }  
  board += "\n" 
  };
console.log(board);
```

With this above code, the start, end and middle of the diamond work correctly with any dimensions. But I cant figure out how to scale the middle rows, rows between the start or end and the exact middle. The Y trigger could alternate odd and even, and I think that would work. But the X trigger needs to branch in the higher dimensions, in such a way that I don't know how to express it.

Here is another dimond:

```
var board = "";
var dimondX = 8;
var dimondY = 8;
for (y = 0; y <= dimondY; y++) {
for(x = 0; x <= dimondX; x++) {
        if ((y == 0 || y == dimondY ) && (x == dimondX / 2 )){ 
        board += "#" }
        else if (( y == 1 || y == 7 )  && (x == 3 || x == 5)) {
        board += "#" }
        else if (( y == 2 || y == 6) && ((x % 2 == 0) && x > 1 && x < 8 )) {
        board += "#" }
        else if (( y == 3 || y == 5) && (x % 2 !== 0)) {
        board += "#" }
        else if (( y == dimondY / 2) && (x % 2 == 0)) {
        board += "#" }
        else { 
        board += " " }
}  
board += "\n" 
};
console.log(board);
```

As can be seen. Nothing needs to be done to the start end and direct middle row, but everything in-between needs to be manually tweaked. The formula for the X axis after the first row would be, x == (1 - (dimondX / 2) || (x == (1 + (dimondX / 2). Then from there each point would have a + 1, -1. I just dont know how to express that.

Not really looking for a direct answer more a hint, or even a 'this is not a viable direction'.

Comment: please add a wanted result of 1, ... 5. You may add a declaration and initialisation of `var board = '';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the question, I like puzzles, and I really liked this one. Here is my version, I have made a generalized version, the length is dynamic you can put any number

```
var board = '';
var N = 10;
var M = N/2;

for (y = 0; y <= N; y++) {
    for(x = 0; x <= N; x++) {

        c = Math.abs(M * -Math.floor(y/M) + y % M);
        if(c==N) c = 0;

        if(  (x >= M-c && x <= M+c) && (x % 2 == y%2) )
            board += "#";
        else
            board += " ";
    }
    board += "\n"; 
}
console.log(board);
```

Comment: Yes puzzles are why I have enjoy learning programing so far. Interesting solution. I sort of guessed I would need another variable or two. I knew i needed to limit the scope of X, but  I would never get it this way yet, not knowing math.abs or math.floor. Thanks!

Comment: abs is absolute value (removing the negative sign), floor is removing the right side numbers from point in a floating point number to a make it an integer number, you can always search internet for the details